# XSLT for-each select syntax

Tags: xml, xslt

I've inherited a gross xslt project - I can't figure out how this line of code reads

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='CustomerOrderLine'][count(. | key('orderline-by-ShipAddress', *[local-name()='CustomerOrderPostalAddresses']/*[local-name()='CustomerOrderPostalAddress']/*[local-name()='PostalAddress']/*[local-name()='Line3'])[1]) = 1]">
```

I understand that this for-each is selecting 'CustomerOrderLine' nodes based off something to do with the 'orderline-by-ShipAddress' key and some kind of union between it and the current node.

I'm looking to understand how this code "reads" so I can better understand how it's working and what I'll need to change in order to re-use the technique.

Comment: Can you post the xslt snip and the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about Muenchian grouping here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml. It is used together with an `xsl:key` to group and identify the first item in each group. So that `for-each` processes the first `CustomerOrderLine` in each group where the grouping is based on the value of the `Line3` descendant.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [Grouping Using the Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Basically it is a way to group elements.